# How to send a key press event to X for a key that isn't on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, key, x11

I'd like to send a synthetic keypress event to X. This all seems to work fine for most keys using `XSendEvent` to send a `KeyPress` event. Unfortunately I can't get it to work for a key that isn't actually on my keyboard - in this case the sterling sign £ (I have a US keyboard).

The problem seems to be that the `XKeyEvent` structure needs a `keycode` and I only have a `KeySym` for this sign. `XKeysymToKeycode` returns 0 because there isn't a key for it.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? It may be that I need some rather different approach here - any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Peter you're looking along the right lines. Part of the challenge is that the set of `KeySyms` is much larger than the size of `keycode`. You can resolve this by modifying the keymap just before synthesising the event.

Take a look at `libfakekey`: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/libfakekey/tree/src/libfakekey.c

And in particular: `fakekey_press_keysym` function which takes a `KeySym` to send rather than just a code.

Comment: Thanks heaps - that seems to actually work, the modification of the keymap seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I didn't know about that and it sounds like it should work although so far it hasn't either. I wonder if something is subtley not quite right about my X install somehow...

Comment: You could try starting X with an empty Xorg.conf (if you're not doing that already).